# What does the permission "Take Ownership" do for a user that does not have administrator permission?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

So, I was messing around in a virtual machine (Windows 7, but it should be the same in Windows 10) in which I was messing around with folder/file permissions, and then I wondered what would happen if I gave a standard user (no admin priviliges) the permission to take ownership. That did not do anything for the user account. So what does that "Take Ownership option" do?

[Here is a picture of what I am doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nVAD.jpg)

Comment: Take ownership is not related to Admin credentials. It is related to User A Computer A being able to access and read files of User B Computer B, particularly files in the USERS folder which are very secure.  This is usually necessary and useful to get your user files from a disk you have taken out to install a new disk.

Comment: So how does it "benefit" the standard user to have the take ownership?

Comment: If a user changes disk drives (bigger, damaged), their user name (system) is different. Looks the same, but different. So said user would need to take ownership of the old drive USERS folder.  That normally requires Admin credentials. What I am describing happens fairly frequently.

Comment: If you do not understand, I just want to know if giving a user (that has no administrator permission) "Take Ownership" does anything, because it seems like you still need administrator permission to take ownership (a UAC prompt shows up). So if you still need to put a administrator password (UAC), does "Take Ownership" do anything?

Comment: Standard Users can normally not adjust permissions of another person’s or recovered files. An Admin needs to do this.  In some years of business consulting I have not seen ordinary users needing to use Take Ownership. That is an Admin responsibility in all the cases I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Take Ownership" does literally what it says – allows the user to set themselves as that file's owner, e.g. through the same "Security" window or using the `takeown` command. This could be used to allow e.g. a file server's managers to repair ACLs for files owned by deleted accounts or similar, without making them

(File permissions apply only to those specific files or folders – they're *not supposed to* change anything about the account itself, as opposed to the similarly named global "Take Ownership" privilege that *is* account-wide and assigned via secpol.msc.)

---

Note that starting with Windows Vista, the "Security" window uses a different method of changing ownership in order to allow the user to choose *anyone* as the owner, not just the user themselves. This new method requires a different system privilege (specifically the "Restore Files" account-wide privilege that's also found in secpol.msc). Because of that, the button now always requires UAC upfront, even in situations where it *could* have done the job without.

However, the `takeown.exe` CLI tool still uses the original method – it can only *take* ownership – so it does not require UAC and will use the file-level "Take Ownership" permission if possible.

```
C:\>  takeown /f test.txt
```

Compare to `icacls.exe /setowner`, which also lets you specify an arbitrary owner, but generally requires UAC to make that happen.

```
C:\>  icacls test.txt /setowner Fred
```

Comment: But how would you do that? I understand this working for a administrator account, but for a standard user, this would not work, at least it does not work for windows 7.  Again, how does this apply to a standard user (no administrator permissions)?

Comment: The permission is literally what _makes_ it work for non-administrator users. You don't need to have both the file permission and the system privilege – you need to have either one of them. Though note that there are two methods of changing ownership – one only lets the user to set themselves as the owner, while the other method lets the user change the file's owner arbitrarily. "Take Ownership" only gives access to the former method, but starting with Vista the "Security" dialog uses the second method (which needs SeBackupPrivilege, hence UAC). So instead, use `takeown /f file.txt` from CLI.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it, I wonder why it still needs administrator permission to take ownership via the file explorer?

Comment: Because Explorer doesn't just _take_ ownership anymore, it _sets_ ownership – which is a different operation that requires a different privilege than just taking it (and one that doesn't have a corresponding file permission). Note how the UAC prompt appears before you select the new owner, not after, meaning it wasn't programmed to distinguish between the two cases; it was programmed to just always request admin privileges upfront, even if you only plan to set the owner to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The owner has all permissions on a Windows object.

The permission "Take Ownership" alone is useless without a lot of
other permissions, such as Full control.

An administrator will have all these permissions, so one doesn't
really need to give them. A standard user will have none of them,
so just this one permission is not enough.

The `takeown` command needs to be executed in an Administrator prompt
in order to work, because while taking ownership it will also be awarding
the user all the other permissions.